# Cuando intento añadir objetos fisicos con funciones y añadir joints, con una colision, solo me añade el objeto, pero sin fisicas (corona sdk)

Tags: lua, corona

cuando hay una colision entre onTouch (box) y el punto, se añade el objeto en las fisicas, solo el objeto en si, sin fisicas ni joints

```
local physics = require("physics")

physics.start()
physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid" )
physics.setGravity(0,0)

local addTorret

local touchIsActive = false
local previousTime = 0.0
local previousX = 0.0
local previousY = 0.0
local touchX = 0.0
local touchY = 0.0
local velocityX = 0.0
local velocityY = 0.0
local box

local function onTouch( event )

local timeDelta = ( event.time / 1000.0 ) - previousTime
if timeDelta > 0 then
    touchX = event.x
    touchY = event.y
    previousTime = ( event.time / 1000.0 )
    local positionDeltaX = touchX - previousX
    local positionDeltaY = touchY - previousY
    previousX = touchX
    previousY = touchY
    velocityX = ( positionDeltaX / timeDelta )
    velocityY = ( positionDeltaY / timeDelta )
end

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if "began" == event.phase then

    touchIsActive = true
    velocityX = 0.0
    velocityY = 0.0

    box = display.newRect( event.x, event.y, 32, 32 )
    box.strokeWidth = 1
    box:setStrokeColor( 0.4 )
    box:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1, 0.2 )
    box.name = "box"
    physics.addBody(box, "dynamic", { isSensor = true})

elseif "moved" == event.phase then

    box.x = event.x
    box.y = event.y

elseif "ended" == event.phase or "cancelled" == event.phase then

    touchIsActive = false
    display.remove( box )
end

return true
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )


local function ponerTorret(event)
   if event.phase == "began" then
    local obj1, obj2 = event.object1, event.object2
    if (obj1.name == "box" 
        and obj2.name == "punto") or
        (obj1.name == "punto" and 
        obj2.name == "box") then

         addTorret = display.newRect(box.x, box.y, 30, 30)
    addTorret.name = "Torret"
    physics.addBody(addTorret, "dynamic", { isSensor = true})
    physics.newJoint( "weld", punto, addTorret, addTorret.x, addTorret.y)

    end



  end
  end

Runtime:addEventListener("collision", ponerTorret)


local punto = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX,                                         
display.contentCenterY, 5)
punto.name = "punto"
physics.addBody(punto, "dynamic", {isSensor = true, radius = 5})
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seria importante poner un esquema de lo que quieres lograr para entender mejor el papel que desempeña el `box` en tu juego.

Realmente no uso Corona SDK pero este se basa en [Box2D](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_fixture.html). Cuando empleas el `isSensor = true` este registra los eventos de colisiones pero no las genera, es decir esto puedes emplearlo para objetos coleccionables como monedas por ejemplo, a efecto de que el personaje no se estrelle con estas... sólo se registra el evento de la colisión, sube tu marcador y la moneda en cuestión, la remueves del escenario.

Por otro lado te sugiero revisar la documentación de eventos de Corona SDK por que ellos emplean a grandes rasgos dos formas para llamar a los `listeners` (Detectores) y esto puede incidir en el rendimiento de tu aplicación por las fugas de memoria que se van generar de lo que veo en tu código `(memory leaks)`

```
-- Detector Estandar touch en un objeto
miObjecto:addEventListener( "touch", myTouchListener )

-- Detector de Evento en tiempo de ejecución "system"
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

El primero es mejor porque no te tienes que preocupar después si eliminas las cajas... o pasas al siguiente nivel ya que la memoria es local. Es más me decanto por el Detector de Tabla 2 ([Table Listener 2](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/tap/index.html)) por que no sólo evitarás fugas de memoria sino que el código será más legible.

En cambio los detectores de eventos en tiempo de ejecución `Runtime`, deben eliminarse cuando se haya terminado de usarlos. De lo contrario, continuarán ejecutándose porque el evento `Runtime` es global. Esto no sólo provocará una pérdida de memoria, pero si alguna de las funciones que se ejecutan en el `Runtime` intenta hacer referencia a los objetos que ya no existen, el programa se bloqueará.

Finalmente esto si tiene que ver con `Lua` cuando declaras

```
local box
```

Nota que es sólo una variable y cada vez que toques tu pantalla estarás sobre-escribiendo esta variable (y al usar Runtime tendrás además probablemente fugas de memorias por lo expuesto antes)

Mi sugerencia es que definas

```
local box = {}
```

Podrías limitar el número de cajas también y en el caso de Corona podrías emular una `clase tipo Pool` (es un constructor de objetos que almacena los objetos que vas sacando de escena para evitar perdidas de memoria por renderizado) con esta función que [ofrece](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/group.html):

```
local miGrupo = display.newGroup()

-- crear n cajas e insertarlas dentro de 'miGrupo'
if #box<=n then    
    box[#box+1] = display.newRect(miGrupo, event.x, event.y, 32, 32 )
end

miGrupo:removeSelf()
--OR
display.remove( miGrupo )
miGrupo = nil
```